# What is Tkinter's tkapp?

Tags: python, graphics, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter in Python, and trying to create code to run when a text box's value is changed. All the code I find online uses a mysterious `tk` member of Tkinter widgets, and I can't find any documentation on it! I found it's of type `tkapp`, but there's no documentation on that either.

Where can I find a decent resource which explains to me the workings of this mysterious thing? (Even better, where can I just find documentation on Tkinter? All I can find are tutorials).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best single resource for Tkinter is [this page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) in the Python.org wiki.  There is also the documentation in the Python Library Reference (for [2.7](http://docs.python.org/library/tkinter.html) and for [3.2](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/tkinter.html)).  Unfortunately, because much of Tkinter is basically a wrapper around existing Tk functionality, a lot of the documentation for Tkinter assumes you know Tk already so reading the [Tk documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/) is important, too.

Answer (score 0):

tkapp is the highest "master". If you make a widget on the root window, tkapp is the master of that.